# Roll back functionality in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a requirements like roll back functionality.
The requirement is like when I click on update button, one popup will  be shown on bottom right corner, which will be display for 5 sec having rollback button. If i click on roll back button, the action should be stop.
I need ideas, how I can start action to MVC controller after 5 sec of click on update button. or cancel if i click on Rollback button. Please suggest me how can I implement this using some timer in Jquery.

Comment: You could cheat, run the action after the rollback time has gone, if user don't want to roll back.

Comment: I need to know the ideas. How can I achieve it by timer.

Comment: ??? There was an idea in my previous comment ... See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Comment: Are you looking for `setTimeout` ?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: freedomn-m something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think you should not wait 5 seconds until you send your changes to your MVC controller.
What happens when the user clicks save and leaves the page, within the 5 seconds? The changes wouldn't be saved.

Instead, I would send a change request to the server, but save the previous version of the request on the side. If the user presses "rollback", you simply send a secound change request with the saved default parameters.

Comment: That depends on the process, if it saves a ton of data to tens of databases, it could be very hard to roll back.

Comment: Thats true. But otherwise I think you have to add an extra db colum with temporary changes and execute them via chronejob

Comment: It would be more simple, that the "rollback button" says, that closing the page within the rollback time will roll back the update ...

Comment: But that kills usability. Would you wait 5 secounds ever time you've postet an answer, comment, question?

Comment: We can not create extra columns. Once the data sent to server with API thread, I think it will be done with all job if we close page also. I am correct?

Comment: Once the data is send to the server with your api and the server responded, the data has been changed.